# how to prove that $(1+x)^p$ is a convex function without calculus?

Tags: inequality

How to prove that $(1+x)^p$, with $x>-1$ and $p>1$, is a convex function without calculus? This would exclude using the binomial expansion when $p$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Bernoulli's inequalities.